# How can i add Scrollbar to nav-tab Contents?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using lionbars scrollbar plugins for overlay scrollbar and i want to apply scrollbar to content but unfortunately its not showing. Below is my snippets for reference and help me to solve the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#activity, #locations').lionbars({
    autohide: true
  }); 
});
```

```css
.right-sidebar-wrapper{  
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 24%;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;  
  background: #FFF;  
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 1;
}
#r-s-tab{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80%;  
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#r-s-tab #activity a, #r-s-tab #locations a{  
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://charuru.github.io/lionbars/css/lionbars.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://charuru.github.io/lionbars/js/jquery.lionbars.0.3.js"></script>

<div class="right-sidebar-wrapper">
<div class="right-nav">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#activity" class="text-center" data-toggle="tab"><!-- Featured Activities --><i class="fa fa-grav fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#locations" data-toggle="tab" class="text-center"><!-- Locations --><i class="fa fa-map fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="r-s-tab" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="activity">    
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="locations">     
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/banglaore_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/delhi_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/goa_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/himachal_2.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/mumbai_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/rishikesh_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it has no content thats why its not shwing. do you want a horizontal scrollbar or vertical?

Comment: you forgot to link the font-awesome css

Comment: vertical scrollbar

Comment: it has content like images

Comment: check my answer

Comment: does my answer solved your problem?

Comment: Yeah but i have other div over nav tab so cant keep fixed

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow: auto;` and specified some height

```
.right-sidebar-wrapper{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: i only want nav-tab content to be scroll

Comment: and your css adding to whole div and that i dont want

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#activity {
   float: right;
   height: 325px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: nav tab should be fixed only content should be scroll able

Comment: just try this i think this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

use `position:fixed;` for your `.nav-tabs` and give some `margin-top` to your tabs. so it will not hide under `nav-tabs`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#activity, #locations').lionbars({
    autohide: true
  }); 
});
```

```css
.right-sidebar-wrapper{  
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 24%;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;  
  background: #FFF;  
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#r-s-tab{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80%;  
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#r-s-tab #activity a, #r-s-tab #locations a{  
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}
.nav-tabs{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://charuru.github.io/lionbars/css/lionbars.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://charuru.github.io/lionbars/js/jquery.lionbars.0.3.js"></script>

<div class="right-sidebar-wrapper">
<div class="right-nav">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#activity" class="text-center" data-toggle="tab"><!-- Featured Activities --><i class="fa fa-grav fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#locations" data-toggle="tab" class="text-center"><!-- Locations --><i class="fa fa-map fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="r-s-tab" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="activity">    
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="locations">     
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/banglaore_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/delhi_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/goa_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/himachal_2.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/mumbai_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/locations/rishikesh_2.png')}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```